# Rounded image as background of item list

Tags: android

I have a ListView and I want to items have image background with rounded corner, like in new YouTube Music app for Wear OS. Any ideas how to do that?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JallF.png)

Comment: and... what did you try?

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of hdodenhoff CircleImageView . The GitHub link for the same is here :

> https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Include the dependency in the gradle file :

```
dependencies {
   
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
```

Now you can create such ImageCircleView like this from your XML :

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```